# Start a Network Connection from Shell (OSX)

Tags: macos, networking

How can I start a VPN connection (it's already all configured) from a shell on OSX? I have looked through the man entry on `net` but I don't think that's it. `launchctl` might be more promising...

**Edit:** I've made the title more general because **I think** the question would apply to any kind of network connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this thread](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=22992). Basically you can Applescript it. Here's a full example:

```
#!/bin/sh 
osascript <<END 
tell application "System Events"
   tell current location of network preferences
       set VPNservice to service "Your VPN Name"
       if exists VPNservice then connect VPNservice
   end tell
end tell
END
```

You can even make another script replacing the word "connect" for "disconnect."

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle network connections' state by using `networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled NameOfService on/off`, e.g.

```
networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled "AirPort" off
```

to disable the AirPort connection.

---

Enabling VPN connections this way doesn't connect them (AFAICT) though.

Comment: Yes, `-setairportpower` is more specific to AirPort, but it's just an example. `-setnetworkserviceenabled` is more general. Also, they perform different actions: A disabled AirPort network connection cannot be powered on.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Beck, I put in an answer myself, after a bit of thinking horizontally about it ;)